# Как отфильтровать List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

Tags: java, android

**Помогите пожалуйста отфильтровать  data по содержанию, например по sendlocate**

```
 List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    String[] stocks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      //  stocks[i] = "    From:  " +obj.getString("mylocate") + "     To: " + obj.getString("sendlocate") + "      Name: " + obj.getString("starttime")       ;
        String entermylocate=obj.getString("mylocate");
        String entersendlocate=obj.getString("sendlocate");
        //if(ssendlocate.contentEquals(entersendlocate) ){
        Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        datum.put("mylocate", "From: " + entermylocate);
        datum.put("sendlocate","To:   " + entersendlocate);
        datum.put("three fields", "From:  " + obj.getString("starttime") + "    " +
                "Until:  " + obj.getString("endtime")+ "  $=:" + obj.getString("money")  );
       // datum.put("Forth Line",obj.getString("endtime"));
        datum.put("id",obj.getString("id"));
        datum.put("name",obj.getString("name"));
        datum.put("email",obj.getString("email"));
        data.add(datum);
    //}

    }
```

Comment: Что значит "отфильтровать"? Удалить из списка элементы, не соответствующие условию? Или выделить нужные в новый список? Или вы имели в виду рассортировать?

Comment: Выделить нужные в новый список!, я конечно уже реализовал это внутри цикла, но было бы интересно это сделать в самой data, заранее благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понял, что значит "*в самой data*"? Определить новый класс -- наследник `ArrayList`? Ну не знаю, это дело вкуса и зависит от обстоятельств, но я бы 10 раз подумал сначала. Но если очень хочется, то можно вот так, например:

```
class FilteringList extends ArrayList<Map<String, String>> {

  public FilteringList(List<Map<String, String>> source) {
    super(source);
  }

  public FilteringList filterOut(String key, String value) {
    if (key == null || value == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't bear with null arguments");
    return new FilteringList(data.stream().filter(map -> value.equals(map.get(key)))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
}
```

Но я бы лучше (скорее всего, опять же, зависит от обстоятельств) сделал отдельный метод в том классе, которому такая фукциональность нужна. Можно с потоками, но если с потоками не очень понятно, то можно и без потоков. Выбирайте на вкус:

```
private List<Map<String, String>> filterOutWithStreams(List<Map<String, String>> data, String key, String value) {
  if (data == null || key == null || value == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't bear with null arguments");
  return new ArrayList<>(data.stream().filter(map -> value.equals(map.get(key)))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

private List<Map<String, String>> filterOutWithoutStreams(List<Map<String, String>> data, String key, String value) {
  if (data == null || key == null || value == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't bear with null arguments");
  final List<Map<String, String>> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
  for (final Map<String, String> map: data)
    if (value.equals(map.get(key)))
      filtered.add(map);
  return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Спасибо на добром слове, но мне было бы приятней, если бы вы приняли мой ответ (галочка слева)